# Import DisplaySwitcher in my xcode9 project - not working

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, xcode9

I've installed the pod and updated my pods just to be safe but I sill bet the "No such module 'DisplaySwitcher'" Error. I'm new to swift so this might be me being a noob but help would be appreciated.

```
import UIKit
import DisplaySwitcher

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDrdS.png)
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yo5aG.png)

Answer (score 0):

I install pod. It works fine. I also import in my Xcode 9.2 & Swift 4.Make sure that you install correct pod in your pod file.
Check the GitHub link

https://github.com/khawar512/DisplaySwticher

Image of pod installation.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try building. Modules from CocoaPods don't get recognized by Xcode until after the first build.